# Enable as a primary App ID option is disable in Sign In with Apple - Apple ID configuration

Tags: apple-developer, apple-sign-in, sign-in-with-apple

I am trying to add the "Sign In with Apple" to my existing App ID. After checking the option to enable it, the following popup was shown: with this message:

> If you're enabling an App ID for the first time or for a new app, enable the App ID as a primary. You can use primary App IDs on their own or to enable identifiers for related apps and websites through grouping. To enable an App ID for a related app, (for example, an App ID for the iOS version of your Mac app), group it with the existing primary. This will also ensure that users only need to provide consent to share their information with you once for each group of apps and websites.

[image]

However, I could not proceed because the **Save** button is **disabled**. I could not do anything.

are there any extra configs I missed or are there anyways around to enable an App Id as primary?

Comment: Have you figured out how to solve this issue?

Comment: @VladimirZivanov already able to save it. do you have the same issue?

Answer (score 4):

The UI is confusing, what I did was selecting sign in with apple first then immediately clicking save/continue. Don't click configure yet, save first. Then Click cnfigure and enable primary ID.

Answer (score 3):

First You have to go to **Xcode** > **Signing & Capabilities** > **+ Capability** and Add  **Sign in with apple** as a new capability.

After that refresh the [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com) page and you should be able to select Enable as a primary App ID and the save button should be enabled.

Comment: This does not work for me. Items are still disabled (as in OP's screenshot) preventing selection of a primary app id.

Comment: @Alyoshak Sorry if my reply was late. did you solve the problem? You may want to check if there is an issue with your provisioning profile in Xcode. let me know if it worked.

Comment: @Alyoshak Check my answer above please, it might solve your problem as I have faced the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, indeed the UI is confusing. I see

[image]

and

[image]

I think this means I have it correctly enabled as a primary App ID.